# Apache Beam: how to discard messages?

Tags: apache-beam

I have a pipeline that:

1. Reads messages from pubsub
2. Converts them to a domain object
3. Applies fixed window
4. Sends data back to a pubsub topic

I would like to process only specific messages - for example having a specific attribute and discard all other messages. How can this be done in beam?

Can I simply skip                                 c.outputWithTimestamp(...); for the messages that should be discarded?

My code:

```
        pipeline.apply("Read PubSub messages",
                    PubsubIO.
                    readStrings().
                    fromSubscription(pubsubSub))

            .apply("Convert to DeviceData",
                    ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, KV<String, DeviceData>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Duration getAllowedTimestampSkew() {
                            return new Duration(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                        }

                        @ProcessElement
                        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                            String message = c.element();
                            DeviceData data = new Gson().fromJson(message, DeviceData.class);
                            String sourceId = data.getSensorId() != null ? data.getSensorId() : data.getFormulaId();

                            // use timestamp from payload
                            Long timeInNanoSeconds = data.getTimeInNanoSeconds();
                            Instant timestamp = ClockUtil.fromNanos(timeInNanoSeconds);
                            long millis = timestamp.toEpochMilli();

                            c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(sourceId, data), new org.joda.time.Instant(millis));
                        }
                    }))

            .apply("Apply fixed window", window)
            .apply("Group by inputId", GroupByKey.create())
            .apply("Collect created buckets", ParDo.of(new GatherBuckets(options.getWindowSize())))
            .apply("Send to Pub/sub", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(topic));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I simply skip c.outputWithTimestamp(...); for the messages that should be discarded?

Yes, a `DoFn` can emit any number of output messages per input message, including zero.